# Picasa albums title encoding. Not unicode?

Tags: python, gdata, picasa

I wrote a simple client for Googles Picasa service. What I want is to create a folder with albums title name and download original photo from the service to this folder.
If there is any non-latin characters in title I got an IOError:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '\xd0\x9e\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8c\Autumnal-Equinox.jpg'

Code sample:

```
import gdata.photos.service
import gdata.media
import os
import urllib2

gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()

username = 'cha.com.ua'
albums = gd_client.GetUserFeed(user=username)
for album in albums.entry:
        photos = gd_client.GetFeed(
            '/data/feed/api/user/%s/albumid/%s?kind=photo' % (
                username, album.gphoto_id.text))

        for photo in photos.entry:
            destination = os.path.join(album.title.text, photo.title.text)
            out = open(destination, 'wb')
            out.write(urllib2.urlopen(photo.content.src).read())
            out.close()
```

I tried to decode the title with `.decode('utf-8')`, it does't work.

Comment: what error does decode give ? what is the type of title (print it as repr(photo.title.text) )

Comment: It looks decoded already. Have you tried `.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: @rocksportrocker `repr(album.title.text)` returns `str: '\xd0\x92\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4 \xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7 \xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0'`

Comment: @d-k Yep, I've tried it. The result is the same. For example `repr(album.title.text.encode('utf-8'))` returns `str: '\xd0\x92\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4 \xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7 \xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0'`

Comment: According to http://code.google.com/p/picasapush/wiki/GDataPhotos the title should be unicode, not str. Do you have a hint what the title should be ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

```
@rocksportrocker repr(album.title.text) returns str:
'\xd0\x92\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4 \xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7 \xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0'
```

and

```
@d-k Yep, I've tried it. The result is the same.
For example repr(album.title.text.encode('utf-8')) returns str:
'\xd0\x92\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4 \xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7 \xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0'
```

This cannot be true. If the first statement is correct, the second will cause:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It appears that your `str` object is a UTF-8 encoded Cyrillic string:

```
>>> foo = '\xd0\x92\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4 \xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7 \xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0'
>>> from unicodedata import name
>>> for uc in foo.decode('utf8'):
...     print "U+%04X" % ord(uc), name(uc)
...
U+0412 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER VE
U+0438 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER I
U+0434 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER DE
U+0020 SPACE
U+0438 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER I
U+0437 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ZE
U+0020 SPACE
U+043E CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER O
U+043A CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER KA
U+043D CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EN
U+0430 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A
>>>
```

Also the above is quite unlike the text in the error message: '\xd0\x9e\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8c\Autumnal-Equinox.jpg'

```
>>> bar =  '\xd0\x9e\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8c\Autumnal-Equinox.jpg'
>>> for uc in bar.decode('utf8'):
...     print "U+%04X" % ord(uc), name(uc)
...
U+041E CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER O
U+0441 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES
U+0435 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE
U+043D CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EN
U+044C CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER SOFT SIGN
U+005C REVERSE SOLIDUS
U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
U+0075 LATIN SMALL LETTER U
U+0074 LATIN SMALL LETTER T
# snipped the remainder
```

The REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) indicates that you are running on Windows. Windows just doesn't grok UTF-8. Convert all your text to Unicode on input. Use Unicode for all paths and filenames. Simple example which works:

```
>>> bar =  '\xd0\x9e\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8c.txt'
>>> ubar = bar.decode('utf8')
>>> print repr(ubar)
u'\u041e\u0441\u0435\u043d\u044c.txt'
>>> f = open(ubar, 'wb')
>>> f.write('hello\n')
>>> f.close()
>>> open(ubar, 'rb').read()
'hello\n'
```

Comment: You are right. It's Cyrrillic. `album_title_decoded = album.title.text.decode('utf8')` `destination = os.path.join(album_title_decoded, photo.title.text)` works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @smirnoffs: It works fine only because `photo.title.text` happens (in this case) to be ASCII. To be future-proof, do what I said: Convert **all** your text to Unicode on input. Use Unicode for **all** paths and **filenames**